Allowing unknown tags inside the editor using a wildcard extension
I am trying to create an extension which will catch all unknown tags pasted into the editor and renders them as they are without modifying anything. Here's the extension I wrote to do this:
import { Node } from '@tiptap/core';

const WildCardContent = Node.create({
  name: 'wildCardContent',

  group: 'block',

  content: 'block*',

  inline: false,

  atom: false,

  addOptions() {
    return {
      HTMLAttributes: {},
    };
  },

  parseHTML() {
    return [
      {
        tag: '*',
        getAttrs: (dom) => {
          const attrs = {};
          for (let i = 0; i < dom.attributes.length; i++) {
            const attr = dom.attributes[i];
            attrs[attr.name] = attr.value;
          }
          return {
            tagName: dom.tagName.toLowerCase(),
            ...attrs,
          };
        },
      },
    ];
  },

  renderHTML({ node }) {
    const { tagName, ...attrs } = node.attrs;
    return [tagName, attrs, 0];
  },

  addAttributes() {
    return {
      tagName: {
        default: 'div',
      },
      style: {
        default: '',
      },
      class: {
        default: '',
      },
      id: {
        default: '',
      },
      ...this.options.HTMLAttributes,
    };
  },
});

export default WildCardContent;


The extension works fine and for instance, when I copy a table and paste it (I WILL be adding a table extension later, but I am just checking if it is capable of accepting unknown tags), this is how it looks:

Although lot of mis alignments, atleast looks like a table.
For reference, here's the actual table I copied (https://afd.calpoly.edu/web/sample-tables):

But when I actually retrieve the content from the editor using editor.getHTML(), it converts everything into known tags and renders everything like a paragraph:

Is there anything I am missing that might be causing this?
Again, I will be adding a table extension later, but I am just trying to test how to handle unknown tags.
